# Special character entity display error in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

i am giving `<a href="www.site.com?&section_id=10">ur section</a>` as a value inside textarea

All browsers shows `<a href="www.site.com&section_id=10">ur section</a>`

**But in ie7** display inside textarea is like this...
`<a href="www.site.com&§ion_id_id=10">ur section</a>`

Help me how to avoid this § display i need to print `&section_id`

Comment: Awesome. But why do you have a `&` right after the `?`?

Comment: just for showing stupidity of ie7. sorry i edit my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Others browser**

**Code:**     `<textarea><a href="www.site.com?&section_id=10">ur section</a><textarea>`

**Output:** `<a href="www.site.com?&section_id=10">`

**IE7**

**Code:** `<textarea><a href="www.site.com?&amp;section_id=10">ur section</a><textarea>`

**Output**
 `<a href="www.site.com?&section_id=10">`

**Only code in Above format** is supported by ie7 to display `&section_id` inside textarea

***How stupid IE7 is***